# Testing a component in a microfrontend application

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass, material-ui, react-testing-library

I have created a splitter component in utility app of my microfrontend and I made use of the splitter component in dashboard app. How can i write unit tests in dashboard app ? Also Im not able to import the utility app components into my dashboard.test.tsx file or mock components from utility app , it throws error .

```
>! Dashboard App----> Dashboard.tsx

import { LeftPanel, Splitter,axios } from "mycomponent";
import Home from "../Home/Home";
import { selectData } from "../../../constants/selectData";
import { Inventorytreeviewdata } from "../../../constants/treeData";
import { tabData } from "../../../constants/tabData";
import {rightComponentProps} from "../../../constants/ComponentProps"



export function DashBoard() {

      
  return (

    <Splitter
     LeftComponent={LeftPanel}
      leftComponentProps={{
        tabData: tabData,
        selectData: selectData,
        treeData: Inventorytreeviewdata,
      }}
      data-testid="splitter"
      RightComponent={Home}
      rightComponentProps={rightComponentProps}
    />
  
  );
}
```

```
//Dashboard.test.tsx //not working
import {screen,render} from '@testing-library/react'
import {DashBoard} from "../dashboard"


import { Inventorytreeviewdata } from '../../../../constants/treeData'

const Splitter = jest.mock('@valgenesis/utility',({Splitter})=>Splitter)
jest.mock('../DashBoard',()=>()=>Splitter)


describe('dashboard renders correctly',()=>{
    
    test('tests',()=>{
        
        const {container} = render(<DashBoard/>)
        expect(Splitter).toBeInTheDocument();

    })

})
```

```
// UtilityApp/Splitter.tsx

import { ChevronLeft, ChevronRight } from "@mui/icons-material";
import { Box, Button, Paper, Stack, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import React from "react";
import { SplitterProps } from "./Splitter.type";
import "./Splitter.scss";

function Splitter(props: SplitterProps) {
  const {
    RightComponent,
    rightComponentProps,
    LeftComponent,
    leftComponentProps,
  } = props;

  const [collapse,setCollapse]=React.useState<boolean>(false)

  const handleCollapse=():void=>{
    setCollapse(!collapse);
  }

  return (
    <Stack spacing={0} direction="row" className="templateWrapper" sx={{height:"calc(100vh - 48px)"}} >
      <Box data-testid="leftWrapper" sx={{ position: "relative", backgroundColor:"#fff",borderRight:"1px solid lightgrey",width:collapse?"20px":"335px",height:"100%",transition:"0.3s" }}>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          className="collapseButton"
          onClick={handleCollapse}
          sx={{
            position: "absolute",
            right: "-12px",
            top: "10px",
            p: 0,
            minWidth: "auto",
            color: "#707070",
            border: "1px solid #707070",
            backgroundColor:"#fff",
            boxShadow:"none"
          }}
        >
          {collapse?<ChevronRight/>:<ChevronLeft />}

        </Button>

       {!collapse && <LeftComponent {...leftComponentProps} /> }

      </Box>
      <Box data-testid="rightWrapper" sx={{width:"100%",height:"calc(100vh - 48px)"}}>
        
            
        <RightComponent {...rightComponentProps} />
       
      </Box>
    </Stack>
  );
}

export default Splitter;
```